# Parsing Alamofire NSData to Array

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire to retrieve data from an endpoint that returns a JSON Array. I can get the data successfully down (see in code where the `println()` is successful) however it is failing to parse into an array at the following: `if let trackArrayData = data as? NSArray` - it is hitting the statement as the `println` is firing, however it is returning empty.

Thanks in advance, code below:

```
func retrieveTrackArray(genre: String, completionHandler: (NSArray?, NSError?) -> Void) -> Self {
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: ApiService.apiEndpoint + genre)!)
    var trackArray:NSArray = []

    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlRequest, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL)
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in

            //todo handle other response codes

            if error == nil && response?.statusCode == 200 {
                println(data); //data is populated Optional(<5b223334 31313438 3238222c 22333934 36373334 33222c22 32303036)
                if let trackArrayData = data as? NSArray {
                    trackArray = trackArrayData
                    println(trackArray) //returns empty: ()
                }
                } else {
                //todo handle error here
            }
            completionHandler(trackArray, error)
    }
    return self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `responseJSON` response serializer or you need to manually call `NSJSONSerialization` on the `data`. You cannot automatically convert the bytes inside an `NSData` to JSON without passing the bytes through some JSON serializer.